# Ordenar lista anidada de diccionarios

Tags: python

Necesito ordenar una lista anidada de diccionarios que genero parseando línea por línea un log file.

El problema es hay objetos que no tiene el dato en la misma posición de línea o bien  directamente no tiene el dato buscado, por lo cual al generar la lista (en una estructura similar a *JSON*), los `{key:valor}` no me quedan ordenandos en la misma posición y esto es un problema al convertirlo a `DataFrame`, ya que me duplican las columnas con mismo `key (print ejemplo)`.

**Ejemplo de la lista:**

Caso OK:

```
[{'"distName_WCEL"': 'distName="PLMN-PLMN/RNC-110/WBTS-1002/WCEL-111"', '**dato': [{'CELName': 'EGGALA'}, {'LAC':'592'}, {'UARFCN':'4379}]**}]
```

En la parte resaltada `datos` es donde tengo el problema ya que en algunos casos el dato buscado como ser `CELName` no lo tiene y me lo ubica en la posición 0 de la lista datos

Caso no OK:

```
[{'"distName_WCEL"': 'distName="PLMN-PLMN/RNC-110/WBTS-1036/WCEL-5361"', **'dato': [{'LAC"':'592'}, {'UARFCN':'4358}]}**]
```

Mi idea es ordenar la lista para que quede `CELName` en la última posición siempre o si bien hay alguna manera mas optima como que complete siempre el campo `CELName` por mas que se NO encuentre el dato

Esto sucede cuando lo convierto a `df`, se duplican las llaves por tener distintas posiciones en la lista datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> PD: dejo el dato en crudo del ejemplo y visualizarlo en https://konklone.io/json/
>
> ```
> falla = [{'"distName_WCEL"': 'distName="PLMN-PLMN/RNC-110/WBTS-1036/WCEL-5361"', 'dato': [{'      <p name="LAC"': '592</p'}, {'      <p name="UARFCN"': '4358</p'}]},{'"distName_WCEL"': 'distName="PLMN-PLMN/RNC-110/WBTS-1002/WCEL-111"', 'dato': [{'"CELName"': 'EGGALAV21</p'}, {'      <p name="LAC"': '592</p'}, {'      <p name="UARFCN"': '4379</p'}]}]
> ```

El código que me genera  la lista fail es el siguiente:

```
    fail = []
    i = -1
    for line in f:
    
     data = line.split()
         
     if '<managedObject class="WCEL"' in line:
            fail.append({'"distName_WCEL"':data[3],"dato":[]})
            i += 1
        
            for line in f:
                data = line.split(">")
                if '<p name="CellAdditionalInfo"' in line:
                    fail[i]["dato"].append({'"CELName"':data[1]})
                if '<p name="LAC"' in line:
                    fail[i]["dato"].append({"LAC":data[1]})
                if '<p name="UARFCN"' in line:
                    fail[i]["dato"].append({"UARFCN":data[1]})
             
                if "</managedObject>" in line:
                    break
```

No logro entender como modificar la parte "dato":[ ] y convertirlo  de lista a diccionario y luego ir agregando los datos  buscados (ejemplo -> fail[i]["dato"].append({'"CELName"':data[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTcgH.png)}))

otra consulta al respecto, el log analizado pesa mas de 1GB lo leo con with open ("rnc_all_180321.xml") as f:, pero necesito leerlo en el mismo código en varias oportunidades buscado diferentes datos, y es necesario leerlo nuevamente desde la linea 0 porque no se donde esta el dato nuevo buscado, querría saber la forma optima de realizar esto si con comando f.seek(0) antes de cada búsqueda o abriendo nuevamente con with open , u otra forma, desde ya muchas gracias

Edito con mas consulta al respecto:

No estoy encontrando la forma de poder capturar los datos siguientes leyendo línea por línea como venia haciendo, sucede que encontré un par de datos que no están todos en la misma línea, o sea, esta el nombre del dato en una línea y sus valores debajo, ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

@ abulafia  espero puedas ayudarme nuevamente con este mismo formato de búsqueda línea por línea.

desde ya muchas gracias, saludos...

Comment: He ampliado mi respuesta con código que (creo) leería la lista ya en el formato bueno. No obstante mira mi nota final. Esta no es forma adecuada de procesar XML. Respecto a tu última cuestión, yo creo que `f.seek(0)` está bien, en este enfoque de procesado "manual". Usando `lxml` el fichero se leería una sola vez, aunque luego se podría procesar lo leido múltiples veces para extraer diferente información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que no has elegido la mejor forma para representar la información. En particular me refiero al formato del campo `"dato"`. Lo que tienes es una lista de diccionarios, y cada uno de esos diccionarios tiene una sola clave y un solo valor.

Creo que sería mejor que el campo `"dato"` fuese un diccionario. Es decir, en lugar de contener una lista como esta:

```
"dato": [{' <p name="LAC"': '592</p'}, {' <p name="UARFCN"': '4358</p'}]
```

que contenga un diccionario como este:

```
"dato": {' <p name="LAC"': '592</p', ' <p name="UARFCN"': '4358</p'}
```

Este formato evitaría los problemas que mencionas. Las claves dentro de cada uno de esos diccionarios no tienen orden predeterminado, por lo que pandas te las procesará correctamente y las ordenará alfabéticamente al final a la hora de crear las columnas. Pandas también determinará automáticamente el número de columnas y sus nombres, haciendo la "unión" de todas las claves que vayan apareciendo en cada uno de esos diccionarios. Si alguno de los diccionarios carece de alguna de las claves, pondrá `NaN` como valor en esa celda.

No es muy difícil convertir tus datos actuales al formato que propongo. El siguiente código lo haría:

```
for dic in falla:
  aux = {}
  for d in dic["dato"]:
    aux.update(d)
  dic["dato"] = aux
```

Ahora tu variable `falla` contiene lo siguiente:

```
[{'"distName_WCEL"': 'distName="PLMN-PLMN/RNC-110/WBTS-1036/WCEL-5361"',
  'dato': {' <p name="LAC"': '592</p', ' <p name="UARFCN"': '4358</p'}},
 {'"distName_WCEL"': 'distName="PLMN-PLMN/RNC-110/WBTS-1002/WCEL-111"',
  'dato': {' <p name="LAC"': '592</p',
   ' <p name="UARFCN"': '4379</p',
   '"CELName"': 'EGGALAV21</p'}}]
```

Que puede ser convertido a JSON con `json.dumps()` para probar a visualizar el JSON resultante en la web que indicas: https://konklone.io/json/ lo que produce la siguiente tabla:

[image: Tabla]

La conversión a dataframe pandas podría hacerse así:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.json_normalize(falla, sep="/")
```

Para obtener:

[image: DataFrame]

### Bonus

En todo caso yo limpiaría un poco más los datos antes de crear el dataframe. Esas columnas llamadas "`<p name="LAC"`" son bien feas. ¿No sería mejor que se llamara `LAC`?

Puedes usar expresiones regulares para extraer lo que es el nombre "limpio" (y los datos sin esos `<p` de forma análoga), por ejemplo con este par de funciones:

```
import re

def arregla_nombre(nombre):
  encontrado = re.search(r'"(.*?)"', nombre)
  if encontrado:
    return encontrado.group(1)
  else:
    return nombre

def arregla_valor(valor):
  encontrado = re.search(r"\d+", valor)
  if encontrado:
    return encontrado.group(0)
  else:
    return valor
```

Y entonces podrías procesar tu lista así:

```
falla = [{'"distName_WCEL"': 'distName="PLMN-PLMN/RNC-110/WBTS-1036/WCEL-5361"', 'dato': [{' <p name="LAC"': '592</p'}, {' <p name="UARFCN"': '4358</p'}]},{'"distName_WCEL"': 'distName="PLMN-PLMN/RNC-110/WBTS-1002/WCEL-111"', 'dato': [{'"CELName"': 'EGGALAV21</p'}, {' <p name="LAC"': '592</p'}, {' <p name="UARFCN"': '4379</p'}]}]
for dic in falla:
  aux = {}
  for d in dic["dato"]:
    arreglado = { arregla_nombre(k): arregla_valor(v) for k, v in d.items() }
    aux.update(arreglado)
  dic["dato"] = aux
```

El resultado en tu lista sería ahora este:

```
[{'"distName_WCEL"': 'distName="PLMN-PLMN/RNC-110/WBTS-1036/WCEL-5361"',
  'dato': {'LAC': '592', 'UARFCN': '4358'}},
 {'"distName_WCEL"': 'distName="PLMN-PLMN/RNC-110/WBTS-1002/WCEL-111"',
  'dato': {'CELName': '21', 'LAC': '592', 'UARFCN': '4379'}}]
```

que se convierte a dataframe igual que antes, produciendo este otro, más limpio:

[image: Resultado]

## Actualización

El OP amplía la pregunta y proporciona el código con el que lee el fichero.

Creo que ese código podría modificarse en la forma siguiente para que la lista quede ya con el formato que proponía yo antes, haciendo innecesario el tener que post procesarla:

```
    fail = []
    i = -1
    for line in f:
    
     data = line.split()
         
     if '<managedObject class="WCEL"' in line:
            fail.append({'distName_WCEL': arreglar_nombre(data[3]),
                          'dato':{}}) # <--- dato es ahora un diccionario
            i += 1
            for line in f:
                data = line.split(">")
                if '<p name="CellAdditionalInfo"' in line:
                    fail[i]["dato"].update({'CELName': arregla_valor(data[1])})
                if '<p name="LAC"' in line:
                    fail[i]["dato"].update({'LAC': arregla_valor(data[1])})
                if '<p name="UARFCN"' in line:
                    fail[i]["dato"].update({'UARFCN':arregla_valor(data[1])})            
                if "</managedObject>" in line:
                    break
```

Como ves he cambiado el "dato" interno de lista a diccionario. Eso hace que en lugar de `append()` haya que hacer `update()`. De paso he metido llamadas a `arregla_valor()` y `arregla_nombre()` para dejar datos limpios y no con marcas xml.

**NOTA FINAL**. Procesar un XML a base de .split(), búsquedas de cadenas y expresiones regulares no solo es algo tremendamente complejo y abocado a multitud de errores y problemas. Es también muy ineficiente. La forma estándar de extraer datos de un XML es usar `libxml` y posiblemente hacer consultas XPath sobre él.

Comment: Excelente solución @abulafia muchas gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: Sencillamente excelente lo suyo @abulafia millón de gracias por su tiempo y paciencia... voy a investigar sobre parsear xml con libxml, saludos y gracias nuevamente por todo...